# How to set maxHeight of a nested Menu in Material-UI?

Tags: material-ui

I want to limit the height of the nested menu in Material-I's Menu to 500px. While I can limit the initial/main menu using "maxHeight" there seems to be no way of styling the submenu (listing the nested MenuItems)

Answer (score 2):

In the paper props

```
 <Menu
    id="long-menu"
    anchorEl={anchorEl}
    open={open}
    onClose={this.handleClose}
    PaperProps={{
                            style: {
                                maxHeight: ITEM_HEIGHT * 4.5,
                                width: 200,
                            },
                        }}
                    >
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `nestedListStyle` property (`MenuItem` is basically a wrapper of `ListItem`, where that property is documented)

```
<Menu>
  <MenuItem primaryText="Menu Item 1" />
  <MenuItem primaryText="Menu Item 2" />
  <MenuItem
    nestedListStyle={{ maxHeight: 100, overflow: 'auto' }}
    primaryText="Hello"
    nestedItems={[
      <MenuItem key={1} primaryText="Child 1" />,
      <MenuItem key={2} primaryText="Child 2" />,
      <MenuItem key={3} primaryText="Child 3" />,
      <MenuItem key={4} primaryText="Child 4" />,
      <MenuItem key={5} primaryText="Child 5" />,
      <MenuItem key={6} primaryText="Child 6" />,
      <MenuItem key={7} primaryText="Child 7" />,
      <MenuItem key={8} primaryText="Child 8" />,
    ]}
  />
</Menu>
```

Comment: Are you sure that this works? I can't get it to work - I assume the nested list have very different structures: a nestedList within a List is integrated right below the Menu Item's div while the nestedList of a Menu is a div created right below the body element without the nestedListStyles (or any classes stated).

Comment: Yes, I just tested this again now, and it works as expected. I am at work right now so I can't get to webpackbin, but I will create a quick example tonight if you haven't figured it out by then.  To be clear, I put the above on a plain page by itself, not wrapped in any other components or using any additional CSS.

Answer (score 0):

```
menuItem:{
            overflowY:'auto',
            maxHeight:'100px' //Change it accordingly
}
```

---

```
<div className={classes.menuItem}>
     
    <MenuItem value={'abc'} >abc</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value={'xyz'} dense={true}>xyz</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value={'qwe'} dense={true}>qwe</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value={'iop'} dense={true}>iop</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value={'egx'} dense={true}>egx</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value={'bge'} dense={true}>bge</MenuItem>

 </div>
```